# Django, using sqlite for static content and postgresql for everything else

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite

I would like to get some comments on whether this is a totally crazy idea or not.

I have a django project running postgresql as its main database.  This project has reports that have a lot of dynamic text content depending on values when the report is generated.  I also have things like blog posts which are stored in this database.

Currently, it's quite annoying when moving things from my dev envionment to production because it means I need to replicate what I have done in the dev database into the production database.

I was wondering if I could use sqlite for this kind of static content only, like text, so things that are read only.  I could then have this sqlite db under version control and automatically transfer changes to production this way?  So I would have postgresql as my main db and then sqlite as kind of a static only db for particular content.

Thoughts?

Comment: The preferred form of a database in version control is as an SQL script that creates it. In this form, there would be no difference between Postgres and SQLite.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll look into doing that.  Is there an off-the-shelf way to keep everything in sync across all environments?  Or does the script need to be manually edited each time something changes?

Comment: You can manually edit the script, or dump the database (`sqlite3 dbfile .dump`, `pg_dump`).